# How to cure memory allocation issue on UI thread which is not an issue on command line?

Tags: c#, performance, user-interface, memory, backgroundworker

I have written an algorithm (function) to read in a number of files from a list, manipulate and agglomerate those files, and then store as a single file. This works fine and processes each file in under a second and a half.

To improve the user experience I created a simple GUI to prep the algorithm (input file list, output file location, and processing options etc.). This works fine.

However, the algorithm takes significantly longer to execute on UI thread (Windows Forms Application), over a command line thread (Console Application). I can find no explanation as to why. The command line execution time is close to linear with the number of files. However the UI thread or BackgroundWorker thread execution is very non-linear and very quickly becomes too slow to be useful. See table below. (I killed the 100 file run after 2 hours).

Number of files 1, 3, 5, 13, 20
Command Line Execution Time 1s, 4s, 7s, 19s, 29s
UI BackgroundWorker Execution Time 1s, 7s, 22s, 309s, 441s

I thought this was to do with the BackgroundWorker class I was using to perform the processing, however on removing the backgroundWorker and calling the function directly from a button press caused it to be even slower (82 seconds for 5 files (and caused UI to lock)).

I have now created a standalone static test function, scattered with Stopwatches to performance test and discover the issue.

One thing is highlighted as getting slower and slower with every additional file.

```
stopwatches[21].Start();
byte[] canData = reader.ReadBytes(8);
stopwatches[21].Stop();
```

"reader" is BinaryReader. This was used as both simple files, and ZipArchiveEntry files are being processed.

Other lines of code which are highlighted as slowing, are always memory allocations, either a "new" statement, or List<>.Add functions.

My understanding of BinaryReaders involves them buffering incoming information and therefore allocating memory. Therefore I believe this to be a memory issue. To back this up, watching task manager the UI thread/BackgroundWorker uses significantly more memory than the command line version. I suspect the performance tails off in a non-linear fashion because my machine starts swapping.

What is different about the memory allocation on UI (Windows Forms Application) thread? And how should I adapt my code to execute identically when run from command line (Console Application)?

Comment: Are you doing any updates to the UI to keep the user updated on the progress while you are processing the files?

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm not updating the UI thread at all. I was, I thought this was the issue and have ripped it out and now my test case has none.

Comment: This might be caused by the presence of a `SynchronizationContext` in the UI version - do you do any async processing?

Comment: Hi Lucas, I've ripped out so much, I'm just about left with a button on the form. (I've been fighting this for several days now). Where would I find out if I had a SynchronizationContext, or would I know if I had? I've not heard the term before, I'll search. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks to Lucas's prod about synchronization... I've created a form with nothing but two buttons to a direct call and a BackgroundWorker call... these and the console version are now exhibiting similar execution times. So the issue is something my main/normal app...What would be a route to investigate this?

Answer (score 0):

**Fault Finding**

After creating a working UI that was just as fast as the command line (new trivial UI), I started looking for reasons that my application was performing poorly, I systematically removed code, call backs, methods, data, eventually deleting all components as well, nothing helped. I now had two identical pieces of code, one working well, one not working... So I systematically did a diff of the files in each project folder, tried to understand the important differences (ignore names changes etc.), so I found what I thought could be the issue. I then altered the file outside of Visual Studio, rebuilt and ran... and performance was good. Success, fault found.

**The Answer**

The fault was in the csproj file.

```
<Reference Include="System.Core">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
```

Which I modified to the following

```
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
```

Note both had

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Also: I still can't find where in Visual Studio where this option is set, I did go through both sets of properties before looking in files to check, but even after finding the issue it's still hidden to me in Visual Studio.

I believe this is because I copied the Form from a Form that was upgraded from Visual Studio 2008, and the upgrade process must have completed incorrectly. Upgraded using Visual Studio 2015.

One to watch for... quick last question. Should I now update the title (main question) to better articulate the actual problem?

Comment: Concerning "Also: I can't find where in VS..." perhaps you mean in the upper right, Solution Explorer. A right click on the project name / properties / Application Tab ---> http://i.imgur.com/5u7zRhi.jpg